# JAR: Could not find the main class

Tags: java, jar

It is a typical error message, yet no search result could help me. I am trying to build & run  a java tool someone coded.

I get the following error:

```
Could not find the main class: ConnJKSEngine.  Program will exit.
```

Here is my manifest:

```
Main-Class: ConnJKSEngine
```

I also changed this to

```
Main-Class: ConnJKSEngine.ConnJKSEngine
```

and

```
Main-Class: ConnJKSEngine/ConnJKSEngine
```

(it has a newline at the end). Did not make any difference

This is how I build the jar:

```
javac -cp ConnJKSEngine/ ConnJKSEngine/ConnJKSEngine.java
jar -cvfm ConnJKSEngine.jar ConnJKSEngine/ConnJKSEngineManifest ConnJKSEngine/*.class
chmod +x ConnJKSEngine.jar
```

This is how I try to run the jar (tried all of them):

```
java ConnJKSEngine.jar
java -jar ConnJKSEngine.jar
java -cp ConnJKSEngine.jar ConnJKSEngine
```

This is the table of contents as given by `jar -tf ConnJKSEngine.jar`

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ConnJKSEngine/ConnJKSEngine.class
ConnJKSEngine/ConnJKSEngine_GenKey.class
ConnJKSEngine/ConnJKSEngine_GetPubKey.class
ConnJKSEngine/ConnJKSEngine_Operation.class
ConnJKSEngine/ConnJKSEngine_PrivDec.class
ConnJKSEngine/ConnJKSEngine_Sign.class
```

I've changed to the `ConnJKSEngine` directory and executed `java ConnJKSEngine`, it correctly prints usage information. This makes me sure that the main class exists and can be executed. So something must be wrong with building the jar, right?

So I went ahead and unpacked the jar to a different directory (`unzip ConnJKSEngine.zip`) and got the directory structure shown above. If I head into `ConnJKSEngine` directory and execute `java ConnJKSEngine`, it executes correctly.

Here I am stuck: The class is in there, it is in the subdirectory and it can be executed. The manifest seems to be correct. Since I am not a java programmer, I come here now. Any idea what could be going on? (note: Linux system)

**Edit** The sources can be found here: https://github.com/Javex/JKSEngine

Comment: Have you attempted to contact the coder or producer of the software or any entity which is currently supporting this code?

Comment: to you have the source ?

Comment: Yes, but he has no time to look into this at the moment and had no idea of the top of his head.

Comment: @Toilal Yes I do have the sources, I added them above

Comment: Is the fully qualified class name `ConnJKSEngine`? maybe `ConnJKSEngine.ConnJKSEngine`?

Comment: Using the package name with the class name in the manifest would seem right to me.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I tried to alter my mainfest to this (see above) and also just ran `java -cp ConnJKSEngine.jar ConnJKSEngine.ConnJKSEngine` which resulted in the same error only with `ConnJKSEngine.ConnJKSEngine` as the class not found

Comment: What is the fully qualified class name? What is package name for your class(es)?

Comment: @javex from your last update it seems the FQN of the class is simply ConnJKSEngine. See my updated answer for how to (try to) fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your main class should have fully qualified name `ConnJKSEngine.ConnJKSEngine` or your jar content should look like this:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ConnJKSEngine.class
ConnJKSEngine_GenKey.class
ConnJKSEngine_GetPubKey.class
ConnJKSEngine_Operation.class
ConnJKSEngine_PrivDec.class
ConnJKSEngine_Sign.class
```

Comment: Okay that was a good approach: I managed to build it by changing into the `ConnJKSEngine` dir and build it there. But how to I build it if I want to be outside of that directory (because changing the main class did not help as can be seen above)

Comment: You can try `-C` option to change directory while creating jar file.

Comment: Ok, I now do this:  `cd ConnJKSEngine && jar -cvfm ConnJKSEngine.jar ConnJKSEngineManifest *.class && mv ConnJKSEngine.jar .. && cd ..`, works perfectly. Thanks for your suggestion. I did try the -C thing but it seems I have to do this for every file seperately. Thats way too much work, so I will stick with that, it's a lot easier :)

Answer (score 0):

If ConnJKSEngine is in default package (no package statement), ConnJKSEngine.class and all other classes should be at root in the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

Given this sentence

> I've changed to the ConnJKSEngine directory and executed java
>   ConnJKSEngine, it correctly prints usage information

I guess the full class name is simply ConnJKSEngine, ie without any package. In this case, the manifest class needs to declare

```
Main-Class: ConnJKSEngine
```

as per your first attempt, but you did a **wrong package**, ie all the classes must be directly put in the archive, not in a subdirectory named after the project (it seems that to avoid name clashes, the developer prepended each class *actual name* with a prefix - bad practice). So you need to put all your *.class files in the JAR like this

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ConnJKSEngine.class
ConnJKSEngine_GenKey.class
ConnJKSEngine_GetPubKey.class
ConnJKSEngine_Operation.class
ConnJKSEngine_PrivDec.class
ConnJKSEngine_Sign.class
```

You could try the following commands

```
# change to project directory
cd ConnJKSEngine
# compile every *.java file
javac *.java
# build the final archive
jar cmvf jksengine-1.0.jar ConnJKSEngineManifest *.class
```

Here are the documentation for [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) (compiler) and [jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) (archiver)

Answer (score 0):

> The manifest text file must end with a new line or carriage return.
>   The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a
>   new line or carriage return.